# Couldn't connect my python rest api to mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, api, rest, heroku

while running the rest api which is deployed in heroku. I am getting below error which says not able to access mongodb

[image: Log preview]

Currently i am accessing mongodb using `pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")` ,may i know how to configure this ,so that i can access the db .

Thanks
Sumesh

Comment: Where is your mongo db hosted?

Comment: I haven't hosted it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that you haven't hosted the DB somewhere, I'll explain how to set things up with mLab and get the DB up and running.

1. Create an account in [mLab](https://mlab.com/) and create a database in it.
2. Then create a user inside that database. We can use this to deploy your local database to mLab
3. Create a dump of your DB

```
mongodump -d <DB_NAME>
```

4. Then restore the db to your mLab instance

```
mongorestore -h <DB_URL> -u <DB_USERNAME> -p <DB_PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase <MLAB_DB_NAME> -d <LOCAL_DB_NAME> <DB_DUMP_LOCATION>
```

5. After successfully deploying the db, you can set the connection string in Heroku

```
heroku config:set MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://username:password@<DB_URL>/<DB_NAME>
```

6. Then, set the connection string in python application

```
import os
pymongo.MongoClient(os.environ['MONGOLAB_URI'])
```

For more info:

https://medium.com/miguel-garcia/heroku-and-mlab-with-mongodb-free-the-easy-way-ec2ae80073f7

https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-deploy-your-mongodb-app-to-heroku/19347

Comment: mlab is disabled, but connected through mongodb atlas. below is the URI i used mongouri="mongodb+srv://Sumesh:"+urllib.parse.quote("password")+"@covid.napki.mongodb.net/Covid?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Comment: Great Sumesh! :)